# Java Code for quering REST API is very slow

Tags: java, json, rest, optimization

I am using following code for querying REST API but it is very slow. Where as response time for browser is in milliseconds. I think there is no issue in API.

Could anyone please suggest what changes I should do to optimize it? Thanks for your time

```
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(URI);

    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

    String line = "";
    StringBuilder outputLine=new StringBuilder();
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {

        outputLine.append("\n"+line);

    }
    return (JSONObject)new JSONParser().parse(outputLine.toString());
```

Comment: Have you tried adding logging lines to various points in the code to find out whether it's the request, reading the input stream, or parsing the json that's taking so long?

Comment: What is "very slow"? One millisecond? One minute? How big is the data?

Comment: Thanks Dave for nice advice. It is taking time to get response which is about 25 seconds.

Comment: Hi Maaartinus, data is not that big in KB's but reponse time is on an average 25 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would expect the biggest delays are in the time;

- it takes to get a reply
- the time it takes to build a JSONObject.

You can speed up how the text is copied as follows but it might not make much difference.

```
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
char[] chars = new char[4096];
Reader rd = new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent());
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

for (int len; ((len = rd.read(chars)) > 0;)
     sw.write(chars, 0, len);

return (JSONObject)new JSONParser().parse(sw.toString());
```

This is faster as it copies up to 4 KB at a time without breaking the text into lines and having to assemble it back into one block of text.

Comment: I agree with you Peter I think its taking time to get Reply. I calculated average time and its about 25 Seconds not sure why. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You should look in toont [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) with [okhttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/). With those libraries you can easly communicate with a rest API and it also parses the body to json automatically.